# Android horizontal swipe top menu

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a horizontal swipe panel much like the one in the Google Play Store.

however, i only want the top menu panel itself to be swipe-able, the content below (which is a ListView) shall not be swiped, the data of the list reloads based on which menu-icon the user swipes to.

does anyone know how i can achieve that? i have been reading on ViewPager (which i presume is what Google Play Store is using) but it seems to be swiping the entire page instead of just the panel itself.

thank you so much all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a blogpost which was discussing this "SwipeyTabs" [here](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html)

The full code for the sample can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/